# Best way to display 300 000+ images online?

Tags: image, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to display so many images ? Maybe something like google maps, that would show all images at once as tiles and you could zoom in and see the picture in detail... ?

Comment: Take a look at google photos for inspiration maybe? Hint: they're certainly not displayed all at once.

Comment: shouldn't it be possible the same way google maps do it ? they show the whole picture when you zoom out, but its getting progressively tilled when you go in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took very long time to process and finish, but I made it ! It CAN be done. correct tools are libvips and its python version pyvips I managed to get all 366 000+ pictures in one, and then made zoomable pyramid dzi with it ! To display it OpenSeadragon since the final picture was 81GB and nothing can open that.... http://deepzoom.reverz.sk/ ( also not sure why my question was down voted :-/ )

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be easily solved by merging all images side by side like a collage.
This task can be automated by using python using its **pyautogui** module and any simple software for image manipulation.
By doing this a single image of very high resolution can be obtained achieving your purpose.
(Although the size of the image would be mind blowing.)

See these sites for similar works (1.2 Billion images) but with smarter solution (the are loading few images at a time upon zooming).

[All 1.2-Billion Facebook Profile Pictures On One Page](http://geekologie.com/2013/09/all-12-billion-facebook-profile-pictures.php)

[The Face of Facebook](http://www.thefacesoffacebook.com/)

Comment: Thats exactly what I need :D

Comment: I guess there is no such open source software just sitting around the web somewhere, right ?

Comment: @VladoPortos You can refer to this book last chapters relevant to your task i.e **Chapter 18: Controlling the Keyboard and Mouse with GUI Automation** @ [Automate The Boring Stuff With Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/).